# Show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

$(a_n)$ is a sequence of strictly increasing positive numbers and has a lower as well as an upper bound. The question is, if the partial sum:

\begin{align*}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)&=\left(\frac{a_{1+1}}{a_1}-1\right)+\left(\frac{a_{2+1}}{a_2}-1\right)+\cdots +\left(\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}-1\right)\\&=\frac{a_2}{a_1}+\frac{a_3}{a_2}+\cdots +\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}-k.\end{align*}

converges? Because $(a_n)$ is a sequence of strictly increasing positive numbers, we have $a_{n+1}>a_n$ for all $n$. Because $(a_n)$ is bounded, we have an upper bound, e.g. $a$, and a lower bound, e.g. $b$, such that $b \leq a_n \leq a$ for all $n$. This means that $b \leq a_n < a_{n+1} \leq a$...

The problem with that is: if $k \rightarrow \infty$, then the series diverges, because of the $-k$ at the end of the expression?! Is there some kind of trick or something to use here?!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Best Regards,

Ahmed Hossam

Comment: Note that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges since it is increasing and bounded above. Hence, the fractions $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ tend to $1$ so that your summands $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1$ tend to $0$. Hence, the "$-k$" is not a problem. Of course summands tending to zero is just a necessary, not a sufficient condition for the series to converge.

Comment: You mean 
$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1\right) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1 =  \frac{\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1}}{\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n} - 1 = \frac{a}{a} - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0 $
? 

Is this the same as  $\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)$?

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)=\underbrace{\left(\overbrace{\frac{a_{1+1}}{a_1}}^{>1}-1\right)}_{>0}+\underbrace{\left(\overbrace{\frac{a_{2+1}}{a_2}}^{>1}- 1\right)}_{>0}+\cdots +\underbrace{\left(\overbrace{\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}}^{\rightarrow 1} -1 \right)}_{\rightarrow 0}$$ 

if the terms in the sum converge to $0$, does this mean that, the partial sum converges to something???

Comment: The partial sums are increasing and bounded from above... $$\sum_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} -1 \right) = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n} \le \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_1} = \frac{a_{k+1}-a_1}{a_1}$$

Comment: The last equality is not clear...

Comment: now it's clear.

Comment: @achillehui why don't you just make an answer out of that comment? Because that's how it should be solved, I think.

Comment: @achillehui why exactly is the sequence of the partial sums increasing?

Comment: see details in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given

1. $(a_n)$ is a strictly increasing sequence
2. of positive terms
3. bounded from above.

Let's say $M$ is an upper bound. (*1) and (*2) implies for all $n$,

$$a_{n+1} > a_n > 0 \implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 1 \iff \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1 > 0$$

As a sequence indexed by $k$, the partial sums $s_k \stackrel{def}{=}\sum\limits_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1\right)$ is a sum of positive terms, so it is strictly increasing. More precisely, we have

$$
s_{k+1} - s_{k} = 
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k+1} \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1\right)
-
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1\right)
= \frac{a_{k+2}}{a_{k+1}} - 1 > 0
\implies s_{k+1} > s_{k}
$$

By (*1) and (*2) again, we have $a_{n+1} > a_n \ge a_1 > 0$. This implies
$$s_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1 \right)
= \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{a_{n+1} - a_{n}}{a_n}
\le \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{a_{n+1} - a_{n}}{a_1}
= \frac{1}{a_1}\sum_{n=1}^k (a_{n+1} - a_n)
$$
The last sum is a telescoping sum. Together with (*3), we obtain
$$s_k \le \frac{1}{a_1}(a_{k+1} - a_1) \le \frac{M-1}{a_1}$$
This means as a sequence, the partial sums is bounded from above too.  Being increasing and bounded from above, the sequence $s_k$ converges. By definition, so does the series
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1\right)$.

Answer (score 5):

You can check that it is equivalent to determine whether the series of $\log\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)$ converges, because $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \rightarrow 1$.

Edit: to be more clear:

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1 \sim \log\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right) > 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Thus, the series $\sum_n{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1}$ is convergent iff the series $\sum_n{\log\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)}$ is convergent.

Comment: You mean $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right) \Leftrightarrow \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow  \infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} \log \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)$?

Comment: No. I mean that one series grows to $\infty$ iff the other does.

Comment: Ok, which series is that one series and which is the other?

Comment: $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \rightarrow 1$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$, because the sequence $(a_n)$ has an upper bound. But this is only one term in $\displaystyle\frac{a_{2}}{a_1} + \frac{a_{3}}{a_2} +\cdots + \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}-k$. All other fractions are $>1$, because $a_{n+1}>a_n$ ...

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)=\underbrace{\left(\overbrace{\frac{a_{1+1}}{a_1}}^{>1}-1\right)}_{>0}+\underbrace{\left(\overbrace{\frac{a_{2+1}}{a_2}}^{>1}- 1\right)}_{>0}+\cdots +\underbrace{\left(\overbrace{\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}}^{\rightarrow 1} -1 \right)}_{\rightarrow 0}$$ 

if the terms in the sum converge to $0$, does this mean that, the partial sum converges to something???

Comment: NO !! This is one of the easiest mistakes to make when dealing with converging series. Take for instance $a_n=n$ to disprove this claim in general.

Comment: A partial sum of the series based on the sequence $a_n = n$ ist $1+2+3+4+...+k$. The last term does not go to $0$ as above... What claim do you mean?...

Comment: I mean: if $a_n=n$, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1=n^{-1}$ so the sum of all $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1=n^{-1}$ is infinite.

Comment: Ok, now I see the big mistake.

What does $\color{red}{\text{this}}$ mean:

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1 \color{red}{\sim} \log\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right) > 0$

??