# If $a_n$ is a positive increasing converging sequence then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big( 1-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \big)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have that $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a positive increasing sequence. I want to prove that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big( 1-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \big)$$

converges if and only if $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}a_n \in \mathbb{R}$

I've proved the $\Rightarrow$ direction showing that  $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}a_n=+\infty \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty \big( 1-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \big) \text{diverges}$$

I ask your help for the other direction. I've tried with some conversion tests (for example Kummus and Raabe) but without results

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3037907/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3974173/42969